# Good Summary / Overview of C99?

Tags: c, c99

I just got a comment on Compound Literals wrong and, in the process, stumbled across Variable Length Arrays.  Clearly I have been living under a rock.  What should I read to get a good understanding of the major new features in C99?

Comment: I don't know how this question can be answered without rewording/pointing you to the C99 standard... Is that not a good enough source of comprehensive technical detail?

Comment: ok, how about now?  i know i can go to the standard for tiny details, but i would prefer something like a long dr dobbs article up front.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html mentions a number of features (and their support status in gcc, but that's not the point), for which you can do further internet searches.

Comment: the next revision of the C language (C11) is officially released, btw, but compiler support is still pretty limited (see http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/ClangReleaseNotes.html#cchanges and http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#cchanges for support in current and upcoming versions of Clang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/), 5th ed., covers the major features of C99, and it's one of the better references for C anyway.

A freely available draft (PDF) of the C99 standard is available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: thanks.  guess i need to upgrade my 4th edn!  awesome book, should have thought of that...

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/newinc9x.htm might be helpful so you know what to look for in the standard document...